# Booting EBOOT.BIN displays blank screen?

Tags: windows-7, networking, boot, usb, motherboard

Having trouble finding any documentation on EBOOT.BIN.

Have an [Intel NUC DCCP847DYE](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-kit-dccp847dye.html) as my target device and another working PC as the host.

Would like to load a WEC7 image onto the target device, from VS2008 on the host device, so need to get it booted with [Ethernet and a static IP](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/tabid/72/entryid/202/Configure-Flash-Storage-to-Launch-Compact-7-OS-Image-using-DiskPrep.aspx) via "eboot.bin".

When I try to boot eboot.bin (off a USB stick [configured with DiskPrep](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/tabid/72/entryid/202/Configure-Flash-Storage-to-Launch-Compact-7-OS-Image-using-DiskPrep.aspx)) I get a splash screen for WEC7 and then a blank screen.

Is EBOOT.BIN compatible with most x86 boards and Ethernet controllers or do I need get a different Ethernet boot loader?

If so, how do I know which one?

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, it ***may be*** the issue that EBOOT.bin only sends output through the serial I/O device.

The target currently in use does not have a serial I/O - only HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

S. !

You are almost through as you get the splash screen. I believe you might be getting BOOTME commands from the target system (where you want to run Win CE).

EBOOT.BIN is compatible with selected x86 boards and Ethernet controllers. You can check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447057.aspx for supported Ethernet cards. Though it is for Win CE 5.0, the info is relevant for other Win CE versions too.

Please be noted that the target *MUST* have a supported Ethernet card as mentioned in above links?

*What if you don't get these Ethernet Cards for your host??*

This had happened to me too! The workaround was to introduce a Ethernet Hub in between my Core i5 machine (Host) and the target machine (an older machine with Pentium 4 and RTL8139 Ethernet controller. We have been using it for past one year now and it works so well!!
Hope this helps you too..